# Generating Random Latin Square

Tags: combinations, random, latin-square

I am trying to make a random reduced Latin Square and it looks like the most efficient algorithm is the algorithm introduced by Jacobson and Matthews

> M. T. Jacobson and P. Matthews, Generating uniformly distributed random Latin squares, J. Combinatorial Design 4 (1996):
>   http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1520-6610(1996)4:6%3C405::AID-JCD3%3E3.0.CO;2-J/abstract;jsessionid=CD8E1B9E7531FB739C31F1A33A7BA1E1.f02t01?systemMessage=Wiley+Online+Library+will+be+unavailable+on+Saturday+17th+December+2016+at+09%3A00+GMT%2F+04%3A00+EST%2F+17%3A00+SGT+for+4hrs+due+to+essential+maintenance.Apologies+for+the+inconvenience

in one part they introduce us to $\pm$-moves I don't understand what is $2 \times2\times2$ subcube how to determine if a cell is 0-cell or 1-cell 0r -1-cell;

can please someone explain this to me